# Is there a snapHelper in flutter？

Tags: flutter

I am searching for snapHelper in flutter, somthing like 
[SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.)

Is there a widget like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IeAw.png)?

How do I get it in  other ways?

Comment: yes, use `PageView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a widget  [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper) ,I think  [this widget looks like what you are looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqmq5.png)

and you can get the example code from [flutter_swiper example tab](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_swiper#-example-tab-) 
paste into a dart file and run it to get more knowledge about what this package can do.By the way you need to add your `pubspec.yaml` file like this:

```
dependencies:
  # other dependencies
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer@cipli onat

Comment: I meet  a strange need, a widget like this but need loading more when scroll to the end，how do I get it? @cipli onat